# Run CMD code line in python, see results in terminal Anaconda

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, anaconda

I have this simple code I use to convert files with handbrake

```
"C:\Program Files\HandBrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe" -i c:\folder -o c:\folder2 --preset-import-file "D:\Handbreak\Script\dudeness.json"
```

I want to run this line in python and see the output it generates in the terminal

My Intention is to iterate "C:\folder" and "c:\folder2"

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
import os
os.system("your command")
```

You can then use a cmd script to run python script

Comment: I get output 255 if I try that